# How to call a Spring boot api present in one Spring boot project from another new Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I have 2 spring boot projects A and B,(A is using an SQL Db with MySQL Workbench and Project B is using an MS SQL db,In simple words both use a different type of db )Now A has 2 restcontrollers-

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "/save_tokens", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ResponseEntity<?> storingFcmTokens(@RequestBody FcmTokenBean fcmTokenBean )
    {
      ...
    }

@RequestMapping( value = "/getAllTokens", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTheTokens(  )
    {
      ...
    }
```

Now I am working on project B(Which uses a different db) and I want to access these to rest apis from project B.Project B has some rest controllers and they show up in Swagger,My goal is that these 2 api's (as shown above) from project A must also show up in Swagger and I can make use of these 2 api's from project A when ever I want along with the api's of project B.
I am a beginner in Spring Boot and I looked for similar questions but they were not matching with this question.Any help appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) for this